# C Language: trouble using enumerated variable and type definited in main.c file inside another file

Tags: c, enums, global

I've definited following enumeration and variables inside my main.c file:

```
enum state_codes {  S0,
        S1,
        S2,
        S3,
        S4,
        S10,
        S20,
        S30,
        S40,
        S50,
        S60,
        S70,
        S80,
        fail,
        fsmError
};

enum state_codes cur_state = S0;
enum state_codes old_state = S0;
```

Into another file of my project (with name *othercode.c*) I've to use the *cur_state* variabile and the values listed inside the enumeration inside an interrupt handler so I've written this declaration on the top of the *othercode.c* file:

```
extern enum state_codes; // <-- first warning see below details
extern enum state_codes cur_state;
```

Inside the interrupt handler I've written this code:

```
void EXTI4_IRQHandler(void)
{
     EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line4);

    // FSM state saving inside the external EEPROM
    // cur_state : current state from the main.c file
    uint8_t data_byte;

    if (cur_state == S0) // <-- ERRORS see below details
    {
      data_byte = 0;
    }

    I2C_Memory_Write(I2C1, EE_ADDR_FSMSTATE, data_byte);

}
```

Concerning this function I've the warning and errors reported below:

```
Warning[Pe1000]: a storage class may not be specified here C:\Users\ ... \othercode.c 49 

Error[Pe020]: identifier "S0" is undefined C:\Users\ ... \othercode.c 777 

Error[Pe070]: incomplete type is not allowed C:\Users\ ... \othercode.c 777
```

The first waring is related the declaration:

```
extern enum state_codes;
```

and the other two error to the function at the row that I've signaled into the code with <-- Errors.

What I need to do is referring the enum type variable inside another file so I've declared it extern into this file but seems that this type of storage class can be addressed in this way.
Someone can point me into right direction?

### EDITED

I've solved the issue by redeclaring the enum into the other file as below:

```
enum state_codes {  S0,
        S1,
        S2,
        S3,
        S4,
        S10,
        S20,
        S30,
        S40,
        S50,
        S60,
        S70,
        S80,
        fail,
        fsmError
};
extern enum state_codes cur_state;
```

The code work properly but I kindly ask if this a correct way or there are some other things to be considered.

Thank!

Best regards
Fire

Comment: The `extern` doesn't provide visibility to the individual `enum` values. You need to put the `enum` into a header and include that where ever you use it.

Comment: Thank I've see your answer just after my editing!

Answer (score 3):

You can't make the definition of the `enum` *type* `extern` in itself, since the other compilation unit needs to know the values of its cases. That is, put this in a header:

```
enum state_codes {  S0,
        // …
        fsmError
};
```

And include the header from all files using `enum state_codes`. The variables can still be `extern`, such as your `extern enum state_codes cur_state`.

Comment: If this seems unclear, consider if I made a library with the `enum` and only shipped a header containing `extern enum state_codes;` and an already-compiled binary library to you. How would you _or the compiler_ be able to use the cases, like `S0`, or even know they exist? (This is not so different from `#define`'d cases.)

Answer (score 0):

Typedef it in the `.h` file then #include this file in all `.c` files where you use it.

IMO it is the most correct way.

Comment: `typedef` is not relevant here (not mentioned in the question) and by itself wouldn't help at all.